# Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding

Tags: spring-boot, corda

i try to implement spring web server to a cordapp , but continuously getting same Serialization error.

```
{
"timestamp": 1529999846743,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
"message": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.Collections$SingletonMap[\"state\"]->java.util.Collections$SingletonMap[\"data\"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"exitKeys\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]->net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAPublicKey[\"params\"]->net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.spec.EdDSANamedCurveSpec[\"curve\"]->net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.Curve[\"field\"]->net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.Field[\"encoding\"])",
"path": "/api/obligation/cash"
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an ObjectMapper in a @Configuration class like this :

```
@Configuration
class Plugin {

   @Bean
   fun registerModule(): ObjectMapper {
      return JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper()
   }
}
```

and you are good to go !

Comment: I suspect, this leads to registration of additional mapper in Spring container, but Spring ignore this  objectmapper uses default one... You can force Spring to use registered mapper refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895899/corda-rpc-jacksonsupport-createdefaultmapper-to-use-objectmapper-in-spring-clien

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're trying to serialize an object of class `net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding` and as you can see in the [sources](https://github.com/str4d/ed25519-java/blob/master/src/net/i2p/crypto/eddsa/math/ed25519/Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding.java) this class has no fields, which causes the serialization to fail.

You should add this line to your mapper configuration:

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

then see if the output is what you want.

Edit: According to Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper), you can add this configuration to the default mapper by adding

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
```

to your `application.properties` file.

Comment: I tried both the approaches but non is working in my case
i think this configuration [ https://pastebin.com/iPuN6J83 ] is creating problem when i remove this configuration and add spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
 in application.properties then everything is working fine.

Comment: 1. I made a mistake and you should of course set spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS to false rather than true to disable the exception (which you did) - I already fixed my answer.
2. I don't think the exception has naything to do with the configuration you mentioned, but rather with the object returned by your /api/obligation/cash endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this at class level for the bean:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This error throws when Jackson tries to serialize the `PublicKey` class to `JSON format`.
`Corda` provides `Jackson support` for some intrinsic classes and you have to register that module in Spring:

1. Add `corda-jackson` dependency in your spring project.

   > net.corda:corda-jackson:3.1-corda
2. Register the Corda Jackson Support `Module` for your spring project. You can do it using java config as below:

`@Bean
public Module registerModule() {
    return JacksonSupport.INSTANCE.getCordaModule();
}`

Comment: cordaModule() is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be because of lacking the JacksonSupport or improper configuration for corda-jackson.

In my case:
I already had:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
```

But the error was still there.

1. I added corda-jackson in `build.gradle.kts`.

> ```
> implementation( "net.corda:corda-jackson:4.3")
> ```

2. I added the following Bean JacksonSupport to the `@SpringBootApplication` file.

> ```
> @Bean
>   @Primary
>   fun objectMapper(builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): ObjectMapper? {
>       return JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper().findAndRegisterModules()
>   }
> ```

And still the error was there.

3. Then, I added following line to the `build.gradle.kts`

> ```
> extra["jackson.version"] = "2.10.2"
> ```

4. And it worked finally :)