# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: in corda

Tags: java, json, corda, gradlew

Getting exception while retrieving node info through method in java using spring web server.

This is the code written in custom controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/me", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Party me() throws Exception

    {
        CordaRPCOps proxy = rpc.proxy;
        Party id = proxy.nodeInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0);
        return id;
    }
```

Even I tried by making parameter as:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false in gradlew.properties
```

And also by adding dependency cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:3.1-corda" in java-source.

[PFA, error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipZdo.png)

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037963/could-not-write-json-no-serializer-found-for-class-net-i2p-crypto-eddsa-math-ed ?

Comment: I already tried by adding parameter as spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false in gradlew.properties

Comment: Thank you after adding the following property,

Comment: spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false in my application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what happened to solve the issue or if you solved it at all, but the recommendation definitely would have been to try that gradle setting to make sure spring gets all the environment-like variables it needs.

there are new sample cordapps in newer corda releases that use spring webservers, you can find an example here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp