# Corda RPC JacksonSupport.createDefaultMapper to use ObjectMapper in Spring client

Tags: spring, corda, spring-rest

How to register newly introduced Corda RPC ObjectMapper in Spring Boot?

> Even after having below code in `@Configuration` class Jackson failing to serialize `Party` object to JSON string.

```
@Bean
public JsonComponentModule jsonComponentModule() {
    return new JsonComponentModule();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper cordaRpcObjectMapper(NodeRPCConnection rpc) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = JacksonSupport.createDefaultMapper(rpc.getProxy(), new JsonFactory(), true);
    objectMapper.registerModule(jsonComponentModule());
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> After some tweaks I'm successfully able to register `Corda RPC ObjectMapper` with Jackson with below code.

```
//Register any other custom (de)Serializer classes.
@Bean
public Module jsonComponentModule() {
    return new JsonComponentModule();
}

//Force Spring/Jackson to use only provided Corda ObjectMapper for serialization.
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(@Autowired NodeRPCConnection rpcConnection) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = JacksonSupport.createDefaultMapper(rpcConnection.getProxy()/*, new JsonFactory(), true*/);
    mapper.registerModule(jsonComponentModule());

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule when trying to do the same